# Create 1 UIImage and manually size for retina/non-retina devices

Tags: uiimageview, ios-simulator, retina-display

It seems like a lot of wasted MB by creating a single image and then making it into separate images to fit 1x, 2x, and 3x for iPhone and then 1x and 2x for iPad. I'm making a universal device app game. So now i have to create 5 different sizes for iPhone and iPad retina/non-retina? Can't I just create 1 size and when i place my UIImage in storyboards, then i manually change the UIImageView size to fit the device? I did this and when i used simulator for all devices, all the graphics were the same, nothing looked blurry. So why create 5 different image sizes if it takes up a lot more MB?

I have 40 images. And now i have to re-create all the images for 2x,3x for iPhone and 1x, 2x for iPad?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well you can use all 1x non-retina images for Retina and non retina devices. In non-retina devices your 1x images will look normal as usual. For retina devices you'll be running a non-retina image on a retina device. The non-retina image won't look worse or anything however, if you compare a retina image to a non-retina image than the non-retina image will obviously look worse. Point is it's not necessary to recreate all images if you don't want retina images.